# How to make an overflow hidden only for box-shadow

Tags: html, css

I have an image (height: 500px) which has a box-shadow and which lays over a greenbox div (height: 350px). 150px of that image overlapping the greenbox div at the bottom.

How can I turn off the image's box-shadow after leaving the green div ?

Alternatively to the following code here is a [screenshot link](http://cmichael.de/extern/overflow_hidden_box_shadow.png).

CSS snippet:

```
.wrapper {
  position:relative;
}
.wrapper .greenbox {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 350px;
  background-color: #39a943;
  z-index:-999;
}
.wrapper img{
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 2px #000;
  width:300px;
  height:500px;
}
```

HTML snippet:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="greenbox"></div>
  <img src="image.png" alt="example" />
</div>
```

Comment: please, post your source code!

Comment: Thanks Leandro ! I have enhanced the question and posted demo code snippets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the shadow on a pseudo-element, and clip that

```
.test {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

.test:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px; 
    right: 0px;
    box-shadow: 0px -10px 20px 10px black;
    clip: rect(-100px, 1000px, 100px, -100px);
}
```

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/VJdrH/1)

Comment: Great ! Browser support for ["clip"](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_clip.asp) and pseudo-element [":after"](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp) is sufficient in my case!